# How can I for an array of objects if value doesn't exists in the array it must push to that array, if it does exist it must not push it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to avoid duplicate objects push() in an Array?

```
    let arrOj = [
      {id: 1, name: 'foo', source: 234},
      {id: 2, name: 'bar', source: 23 },
      {id: 3, name: 'test', source: 4},
      {id: 1, name: 'change', source: 234}
    ];
```

loop through this array of objects "arrOj" and push value each object to this new array "arrNew" only if the value of name doesn't exist

```
        let arrNew = [
      {id: 1, name: 'foo', source: 234},
      {id: 2, name: 'bar', source: 23 },
      {id: 3, name: 'test', source: 4}
    ];
```

so I want only push new value to the array if the name doesn't exist

```
{id: 1, name: 'change', source: 234}, // i can push this value
{id: 1, name: 'foo', source: 234}, // i must not push this value because the name does exists
```

Comment: Again: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593

Comment: *if value keys name does exist* / *if the name doesn't exist* **Exist where??**

Comment: can't you just loop through your arr and check for every name if it's the same as the value you want to push ? and if one is the same then don't push

Comment: @colin  yes that what I want to do if the name is the same with the one I want to push then I must not push the object to the array but if the name is not the same I must push the object to the array

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well this should do it

```js
 let arrOj = [
      {id: 1, name: 'foo', source: 234},
      {id: 2, name: 'bar', source: 23 },
      {id: 3, name: 'change', source: 234}
]; 

let arrNew = [
      {id: 1, name: 'foo', source: 234},
      {id: 2, name: 'bar', source: 23 },
      {id: 3, name: 'test', source: 4}
]; 
    
function avoidDouble(newObj){
   let found = false;
   for(obj of arrOj){
      if(obj.name == newObj.name){
         found = true;
         console.log("double found !");
         break;
      }
   }
   
   if(!found) arrOj.push(newObj);
}

for(item of arrNew) avoidDouble(item);
   
console.log(arrOj);
```